# Why does xset s activate immediately deactivate?

Tags: terminal, x11, xset

I believe that the command `xset s activate` is meant to activate the screensaver in X. I tried entering it into a terminal, and it seems to work at first, but the screensaver exits almost straight away (as if entering the command had itself resumed it). i am certain that I'm not accidentally pressing something else after entering the command. On the other hand, if I run `sleep 1 && xset s activate`, then the screensaver persists. How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type

```
xset s activate
```

and then <kbd>Return</kbd>, I suspect `xset` runs before you release the key, so the key up event deactivates the screensaver.

Running `xset` after `sleep` means the key up event occurs before `xset` runs (unless you hold the key down of course, but then it would start repeating).

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. I guess this would not be an issue if run through a script, but I'm surprised that it doesn't work as expected when run from the terminal!